# Scrollify Links

Tags: javascript, html, plugins

I am trying to have links that scroll to the section. I don't understand why this isn't working, the links either don't work or they go to the section without scrolling at all. I am using the Scrollify plugin.

Javascript in the header. Should I put it in the footer? I read somewhere it should be in the header which I thought odd...

```
 $(function() {
            $.scrollify({
                section : ".section-class-name",
                sectionName : "first",
                easing: "easeOutExpo",
                scrollSpeed: 1100,
                offset : 0,
                scrollbars: true,
                standardScrollElements: "",
                setHeights: true,
                before:function() {},
                after:function() {},
                afterResize:function() {},
                afterRender:function() {}
            })
        });

        $(".first").click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $.scrollify("move", $(this).attr("href"));
       });
```

The HTML

```
     <div class="section-class-name" data-name-section="first" style="background-color: red;">
            <a href="#second" class="first">Second</a><br>
        </div>
        <div class="section-class-name" data-name-section="second" style="background-color: orange;"></div>
        <div class="section-class-name" data-name-section="last" style="background-color: yellow;"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your click event.
`$.scrollify("move", $(this).attr("href"));`
Is not correct syntax, it should be:
`$.scrollify.move($(this).attr("href"));`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your value for "sectionName" in javascript is "first", but maybe they're looking for the name of the HTML5 data attribute. For example, in the source for the [Scrollify](http://projects.lukehaas.me/scrollify/#options) plugin website, they use `data-section-name`. In your case, it would be `name-section`. Also, for the "section" option in your javascript, I think they're asking for the HTML tag type. In your case, the value should be `div`.

On the project page they explain the options at http://projects.lukehaas.me/scrollify/#options.

Comment: Not really working- I know the data section name is working. If the URL has the id/data section name on the end then the window automatically scrolls to that section when I load/refresh it. But the links themselves are not working except putting the # section name on the end of the url.